# Trying to modify a Codepen example of a rotating gradient

Tags: css, animation, frontend, css-animations

I've found a great Codepen by Kevin Powell showing how to animate a gradient behind a rectangular card. I'd like to adapt this to allow for the card to be a polygon - specifically an upward pointing arrow. Any help much appreciated

https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/QWVKZjx

CSS:

```
@property --gradient-angle {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}

:root {
  --clr-1: #052b2f;
  --clr-2: #073438;
  --clr-3: #0e4b50;
  --clr-4: #2d8f85;
  --clr-5: #637c54;
}

body {
  background: var(--clr-2);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.card {
  height: 60vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1.5;
  background: var(--clr-1);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;

  position: relative;
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -0.5rem;
  z-index: -1;
  background: conic-gradient(
    from var(--gradient-angle),
    var(--clr-3),
    var(--clr-4),
    var(--clr-5),
    var(--clr-4),
    var(--clr-3)
  );
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: rotation 20s linear infinite;
}

.card::after {
  filter: blur(3.5rem);
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    --gradient-angle: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    --gradient-angle: 360deg;
  }
}
```

I've adapted the CSS and managed to make the card a narrow line by adjusting it's dimensions, but haven't been able to figure out how to place the animated conical gradient behind a polygon.